# Accessing list elements within mutate

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I am trying to use the dplyr 'mutate' command to perform matching over a list of arrays, but am getting an error "Error: recursive indexing failed at level 2"
here is an example:

```
templist=list();templist[["A"]]=c(6,9,8,1);templist[["B"]]=c(1,9,6,8);templist[["C"]]=c(8,1,9,6)

tempdat=data.frame(SYSTEM=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),nums=c(1,8,9,1,8,9,1,8,9))
```

which provides

```
 templist
$A
[1] 6 9 8 1

$B
[1] 1 9 6 8

$C
[1] 8 1 9 6
```

and

```
tempdat
  SYSTEM idnum
1      A     1
2      A     8
3      A     9
4      B     1
5      B     8
6      B     9
7      C     1
8      C     8
9      C     9
```

I then want to find the position of matching numbers the lists corresponding to the appropriate systems. E.g.

```
tempdat %>% mutate(numids=match(nums,templist[[SYSTEM]]))
```

should yield

```
tempdat
  SYSTEM nums numids
1      A    1      1
2      A    8      3
3      A    9      2
4      B    1      1
5      B    8      4
6      B    9      2
7      C    1      2
8      C    8      1
9      C    9      3
```

but I get the above noted error instead

> (Error: recursive indexing failed at level 2)

Can anyone explain why this is failing? Or better yet, figure out a way to get this accomplished correctly?
I have a hunch that it could be done using a for loop to create separate data frames for each list and then use left_join to add the match indices from each system frame onto the original frame, but this seems like it will probably be very inefficient, inelegant, and clunky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it fails is that `[[` for list doesn't accept vector indexing, and variable passed to `mutate` function is essentially a vector. A quick fix would be grouping your data frame by `SYSTEM` and pass `unique` variable to it thus for every group the `SYSTEM` would be a single value instead of a vector:

```
tempdat %>% group_by(SYSTEM) %>% mutate(numids=match(nums,templist[[unique(SYSTEM)]]))

# Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
# Groups: SYSTEM [3]
#
#   SYSTEM  nums numids
#   (fctr) (dbl)  (int)
# 1      A     1      4
# 2      A     8      3
# 3      A     9      2
# 4      B     1      1
# 5      B     8      4
# 6      B     9      2
# 7      C     1      2
# 8      C     8      1
# 9      C     9      3
```

If you check `templist[[c("A", "B", "A")]]`, you will find that it throws exactly the same error as you have seen:

> Error in templist[[c("A", "B", "A")]] :    recursive indexing failed
>   at level 2